# How can I turn caching off in Chrome for a particular website?

Tags: javascript, caching, google-chrome

I'm developing Javascript for a website called www.example.com and Chrome keeps caching earlier versions of my code.  I can continuously clear the cache, but that's becoming a time sink.  Any other options?

Comment: Since you're developing, just output some anti-cache headers at the server and/or script level.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I usually press: ctrl + shift + r to clear the cache. That I find the easiest.

This also works:

```
<meta http-equiv="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1">
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache">
```

Answer (score 17):

If you do not want to change the code for your webpage. You can simply open developer tools on Google Chrome. Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+i on windows.

You'll find a gear on the bottom-right corner that'll take you to settings. Check "disable cache" and you're good to go.

Comment: This would work only when Developer Tools are open. Once closed, cashing would be enabled again.

Answer (score 5):

If you use an incognito window for debugging- it has no cached data. Simple and requires no change to your browser setup.

Answer (score 1):

I do this myself for development. I use CTRL-F5. Its like a force refresh. This refreshes the page including re-downloading any referenced JS files or CSS files even if they were cached.

Answer (score 0):

Add these headers to your web pages during development:

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="PRAGMA" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
```

Or you can configure your web server to put no-cache info in the http headers (during development).

Answer (score 0):

you can add in the .htaccess a rule for not caching a specific file or specific extension

```
<FilesMatch "script.js$">
Header unset Cache-Control
Header unset Expires
Header unset Last-Modified
FileETag None
Header unset Pragma
</FilesMatch>
```

or for all .js & css

```
<FilesMatch "\.(js|css)$">
```

Comment: Not sure why I never thought of this.  I should do this for all of my locally-developed sites! :^D

Comment: This would not work for the other several dozen popular web servers.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting HTTP header:

```
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
```

Or:

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE, NO-STORE">
```

But this should only be used during development.

Answer (score 0):

I've made a Chrome extension that **disables browser cache for specific websites**.

Take a look – it's called [Cache Disabler](https://github.com/AlejandroAkbal/Cache-Disabler-Extension). Here's how it appears in action:

[image: Screenshot of “Cache Disabler” Chrome extension]

With it, you can **see your changes immediately**!

[It's open-source](https://github.com/AlejandroAkbal/Cache-Disabler-Extension), any feedback is welcome!